# Scipy.optimize.minimize much slower on Linux than on Windows with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I have a pretty complex program in Python 3.10 that queues calculations to be executed by workers (multiprocessing.Process).

That runs prety slow on my 8-cores laptop running Windows 11. It runs much faster on a 20-cores desktop running Windows 11.

I have started using VMs from Azure to reduce latency. However, to my surprise, calculations were much slower on the VMs. Code seems to run well on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM with 2 cores. As I increase the number of cores, instead of running faster, code runs slower.

I found out that calculations that just do linear algebra with Pandas or Numpy actualy take less of a worker´s time to run on the Linux VMs. (usually less than *0.1s*) Calculations that call an optimization function, however, take on averave *2s* of a worker´s time on Windows, and *3min30s* on Linux when on a 16-cores machine (with the same amount of RAM).

Doing an `htop` on the VM, I see all cores at 100% of CPU usage. However less than 15% are green bars (normal time spent), and more than 85% are red bars (kernel / blocking time).

It seems multiple threads are competing for some resource on Linux, but that is not noticeable on Windows.

The optimization function calls `scipy.optimize.minimize`. The function to minimize is compiled with `numba.njit` and does some linear algebra math, and has several constraints.

The Windows environment runs Python 3.10 (Anaconda).

The Linux environment runs Python 3.10 from Miniconda, with vanila requirement installations.

Does anybody have a suggestion of how to find out where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the problem!

I used **yappi** to profile the computation, while other computations were running using multiprocessing. Among the functions that stood out as consuming most wall time, stood out a very basic function that was taking 56 seconds (1/3) of computation time: **numpy.dot**

My hypothesis is that the problem is with **numpy**, not **scipy.optimize** itself, and that the problem was much more noticeable when performing optimizations because other, simpler calculations, actualy spend a significant part of CPU time doing serializations and deserializations of data, while optimize was much heavier on numpy calculations.

I tried a few proposed workarounds, and one of them actualy worked: setting the following environment variables before loading numpy:

```
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "2"
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "2"
```

I tried different values, 1, 2, and 4. 2 worked best for my system. Curiously, when running *Task Manager* on Windows, it was possible to see that each python process was consuming up to 200% of CPU time (whithout doing any setting manually). On Linux, all processes could be at 800% (meaning they would be trying to use up to 8 cores) before that setting, and with the setting they go up to 200%, as in Windows.